# How to add +8 hrs in current-dateTime() for date functions in schematron/xslt.

Tags: schematron

I am working on schematron Validations, in that validation I have one rule in which is Date should not be greater than current date. rule is fine but my problem is I validate the Date as per PST and client having GMT timestamp for date, there is 8 hrs difference so please help how to add +8 hrs in validation rule of schematron, if there is having some mechanisum to compare those timestamps then please answer in comment. thanks to all in adv.

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath date functions respects the timezone, if it is known. So it depends on, how you write your date into the file.

If you write it in this format:

```
<date>2016-06-23T11:30:34.000-10:00</date>
```

the timezone should be respected.

If this is not possible, you can add the 8hrs manually:

```
current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT08H')
```

[Edit:] see the declaration of [xs:dayTimeDuration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dt-dayTimeDuration)

In this cases you may need a new namespace declaration for the xs prefix:

```
<sch:ns uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" prefix="xs"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me @Nico Kutscherauer